# How does one computer have HDMI option in sound settings and one doesn't?

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have 2 computers, both have Ubuntu 18.04.  When I select the "settings" icon, neither had an HDMI option in the sound settings until I just looked recently and this computer now has an HDMI selection and the other computer doesn't.  The other computer had 14.04 and there was the HDMI option in that sound setting too, but I just installed 18.04 on the other and took all the updates and there is no HDMI option.  How does that happen and how do I change it?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on the graphics card the computer has - not all of them are supported on Ubuntu for audio over HDMI "out of the box" - sometimes you need to [install an additional proprietary driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers).

Comment: I don't understand how that computer had the HDMI option with 14.04 and not with 18.04.  It has the same sound card, but that option is not available.  When 18.04 was installing I checked the box to include the extra drivers.   And this computer didn't have the HDMI option and now it does.  In that link you gave it is pretty generic, do I just install everything like they suggest?  Also, that seemed to be more about video than audio.  I get the video through the HDMI port..

Comment: Another puzzling thing, in that link they say to select the "settings" icon and their picture has a window with all those icons for the different settings.  I have seen that before but right now, mine just has a list of 16 items, none of them is the "sources" they say to check out.

Comment: What video card are you using in these systems?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1194969/edit) your question and add some more details about the hardware you are using and what driver you are installing onto these hosts for the video.

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant.  The hardware is not the problem because when I had 14.04 installed, and went to the settings for sound, there is an HDMI option in the window.   With the same hardware, when I installed 18.04, on that same computer, and go to the sound settings, there is not an HDMI in the window.

Comment: Do I get extra points for asking questions that no one can answer?  At least I don't understand the relevance of the kind of hardware when that same hardware works for one version of Ubuntu and not for the other.  Logically, it seems that the hardware is not the issue.